# Getting Reference Document in Firestore with React using react-redux-firebase

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I'm working with a collection which documents looks like these

```
Visit {
  point: document-ref
}
```

the point contains the lat and long for the point.

As you can see, I'm retrieving the document for each visit. But I'm also having a huge problem: **I'm rocketing my cloud usage**.

Is there a way to do this without getting my usage up in the sky?

I'm using react with with `react-redux-firebase`

```js
  useSelector(({ firestore: { ordered: { visitas } } }) => {
    return (
      visitas &&
      Promise.all(
        visitas.map(async v => {
          return { ...v, punto: (await v.puntoId.get()).data() };
        })
      ).then(v => {setVisitas(v)})
    );
  });
```

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the documents, with the point already loaded in it.